# Entity Framework Core 2.2 not reseting after tear down while unit testing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mstest, xunit

I'm attempting to write some unit tests to cover as much of my api as possible, but instead of using a database I've decided to use the InMemory provider, not to test that EF works, rather that my implantation is correct, but what I'm running into is a strange side effect.

Essentially what is happening is the id values for objects that are seeded, are not resetting after each test.

In MSTest I've implemented a setup to create a new database context for each test, providing a new name for each test run and am making sure to call `EnsureCreated()`  before seeding my database. In addition I'm also implementing a TearDown to ensure that the database is correctly disposed.

```
[TestClass]
public class CountryTests
{
    private CdiContext Context { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        DbContextOptions<CdiContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CdiContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: $"{Guid.NewGuid()}")
            .Options;

        Context = new CdiContext(options);
        Context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        Seed();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }

    private void Seed()
    {
        var service = new CoreDataService(Context);

        var regions = new List<Region>
        {
            new Region
            {
                Name = "Asia",
                State = RecordState.Active,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },

            new Region
            {
                Name = "Africa",
                State = RecordState.Active,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },

            new Region
            {
                Name = "South America",
                State = RecordState.Active,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            }
        };

        Context.Regions.AddRange(regions);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CanAddCountry()
    {
        //-- arrange
        var service = new CoreDataService(Context);

        var userId = "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB";
        var region = await service.GetRegionById(1);

        var country = new Country
        {
            Name = "Canada",
            State = RecordState.Active,
            UserId = userId,
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            RegionId = region.Id
        };

        //-- act
        var results = await service.AddCountry(country);

        //-- assert
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Name == "Canada");
        Assert.IsTrue(results.UserId == "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB");
        Assert.IsNotNull(results.Region);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CanGetCountries()
    {
        //-- arrange
        var service = new CoreDataService(Context);

        var userId = "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB";
        var region = service.GetRegionById(1);
        var names = new[] {"Canada", "Wales", "Japan", "Australia", "Hawaii", "Germany"};

        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            await service.AddCountry(new Country
            {
                Name = names[x],
                State = RecordState.Active,
                UserId = userId,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                RegionId = region.Id
            });
        }

        //-- act
        var results = await service.GetCountries();

        //-- assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(results);
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Count == 5);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task CanDeleteCountry()
    {
        //-- arrange
        var service = new CoreDataService(Context);

        var userId = "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB";
        var region = service.GetRegionById(1);
        var names = new[] { "Canada", "Wales", "Japan", "Australia", "Hawaii", "Germany" };

        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            await service.AddCountry(new Country
            {
                Name = names[x],
                State = RecordState.Active,
                UserId = userId,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                RegionId = region.Id
            });
        }

        //-- act
        await service.DeleteCountry(id: 2, userId: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        var countries = await service.GetCountries();
        var country = await service.GetCountryById(2);

        //-- assert
        Assert.IsTrue(countries.Count != 5);
        Assert.IsNull(country);
    }
}
```

Now when I run this, the third test fails, because it can't find the correct id, and this to me is a bit weird.

I initially thought this was a problem with MSTest, but noticed the same behaviour in xUnit as well.

```
public class CdiTestBase : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly CdiContext _context;

    public CdiTestBase()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<CdiContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: $"{Guid.NewGuid()}")
            .Options;

        _context = new CdiContext(options);

        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        SeedRegions(_context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureDeleted();

        _context.Dispose();
    }

    private void SeedRegions(CdiContext context)
    {
        var regions = new List<Region>
        {
            new Region
            {
                Name = "Asia",
                State = RecordState.Active,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },

            new Region
            {
                Name = "Africa",
                State = RecordState.Active,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },

            new Region
            {
                Name = "South America",
                State = RecordState.Active,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            }
        };

        context.Regions.AddRange(regions);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class CountryTests : CdiTestBase
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task CanAddCountry()
    {
        //-- arrange
        var service = new CoreDataService(_context);

        var userId = "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB";
        var region = await service.GetRegionById(1);

        var country = new Country
        {
            Name = "Canada",
            State = RecordState.Active,
            UserId = userId,
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            RegionId = region.Id
        };

        //-- act
        var results = await service.AddCountry(country);

        //-- assert
        Assert.True(results.Name == "Canada");
        Assert.True(results.UserId == "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB");
        Assert.NotNull(results.Region);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CanGetCountries()
    {
        //-- arrange
        var service = new CoreDataService(_context);

        var userId = "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB";
        var region = service.GetRegionById(1);
        var names = new[] { "Canada", "Wales", "Japan", "Australia", "Hawaii", "Germany" };

        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            await service.AddCountry(new Country
            {
                Name = names[x],
                State = RecordState.Active,
                UserId = userId,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                RegionId = region.Id
            });
        }

        //-- act
        var results = await service.GetCountries();

        //-- assert
        Assert.NotNull(results);
        Assert.True(results.Count == 5);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task CanDeleteCountry()
    {
        //-- arrange
        var service = new CoreDataService(_context);

        var userId = "133BC82D-FDE2-4124-9207-CD3465511AEB";
        var region = service.GetRegionById(1);
        var names = new[] { "Canada", "Wales", "Japan", "Australia", "Hawaii", "Germany" };

        for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            await service.AddCountry(new Country
            {
                Name = names[x],
                State = RecordState.Active,
                UserId = userId,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                RegionId = region.Id
            });
        }

        //-- act
        await service.DeleteCountry(id: 2, userId: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        var countries = await service.GetCountries();
        var country = await service.GetCountryById(2);

        //-- assert
        Assert.True(countries.Count != 5);
        Assert.Null(country);
    }
}
```

If I run all the tests at the same time, I consistently get test failures, but if I run each test individually they all pass, and this bothers me.

Comment: This sounds like a concurrency problem to me. Can you please make sure that the "Execute tests in parallel" option on the Test-Explorer is disabled and try again? I'm not sure if I named it correctly; it's an icon with three arrows pointing to the right.

Comment: Somehow it feels like an issue with the Test execution order. When you run them one by one, you are essentially running them sequentially and the Id is present in the database for the delete test to find, but when running all in one go, they are not running sequentially. You can create OrderedTests in Visual Studio as well to get around this.

Comment: So I'm running things from both command line and in visual studio. I've made sure that the parallel option is definitely disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with in-memory database auto generated keys, tracked by [#6872 InMemory: Improve in-memory key generation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6872).

It's been fixed in the upcoming 3.0 release - [Each property uses independent in-memory integer key generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#each-property-uses-independent-in-memory-integer-key-generation):

> **Old behavior**
>
> Before EF Core 3.0, one shared value generator was used for all in-memory integer key properties.
>
> **New behavior**
>
> Starting with EF Core 3.0, each integer key property gets its own value generator when using the in-memory database. Also, if the database is deleted, then key generation is reset for all tables.
>
> **Why**
>
> This change was made to align in-memory key generation more closely to real database key generation and to improve the ability to isolate tests from each other when using the in-memory database.

There is nothing you can do currently except to update the test code to not rely on hardcoded auto generated values (which is not good anyway).

Comment: crud. 

I'm guessing there's no way to manually truncate the data?

Comment: Well, you can truncate the data, but not the id generator. You could provide hardcoded id values in the tests though, and EF Core will use them instead of auto generated - see [Explicit values for generated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties)

Comment: It's a framework bug mate, and we can't fight the framework bugs. You can follow the GitHub thread links for suggested workarounds, but as you can see from a recent [response from EF Core dev team member](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15240#issuecomment-479553145) , "*The workarounds for now are to either explicitly specify the key value in the test, or to read back the generated key value and use this in the assertions."* Basically what I'm saying :)

Comment: Nope I understand that, its not the most ideal solution, but its the best we've got without upgrading to 3.0